# how to make if statement in the laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have the following SQL query

```
$query
    ->join('cities','tickets.city_id','=','cities.id')
    ->select(
        'tickets.id',
        'tickets.biker_id',
        'tickets.picked_up',
        'tickets.delivered',
        'tickets.service_charge',
        'tickets.amount',
        'tickets.cancelled',
        'tickets.pre_order',
        'tickets.created_by',
        'tickets.created_at'
    )
    ->whereDay('tickets.created_at',Date('d'))                      
    ->orderBy('tickets.created_at','desc')
    ->get();
```

my aim is to set the

```
whereday('tickets.created_at', Date('d'))
```

to

```
whereday('tickets.created_at', Date('d', strtotime("-1 day")))
```

whenever the **tickets.pre_order = 1**

but when **tickets.pre_order = 0** i will stick to the

```
whereday('tickets.created_at',Date('d'))
```

is it possible using if statement or is there any better way to solve this?

Comment: do it this way by using carbon library, then ->where('tickets.pre_order,1) ->whereDay('tickets.created_at',Carbon::now()->subDay()->format('d'));

Comment: can u make it more clear please?

Comment: so ill just add that code in my query?

Comment: yea but do make sure to import the carbon library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make it like this

```
  ->where(function ($query){
    $query->where('tickets.created_at', Carbon::now()->subDays()->format('d')) 
        ->where('tickets.pre_order',1); 
   })->orWhere(function ($query){ $query->where('tickets.created_at', 
       Carbon::now()->format('d')) ->where('tickets.pre_order',0); })
  ->get();
```

Comment: but  when the tickets.pre_order is 0, i must use ->whereDay('tickets.created_at', Date('d'))

Comment: so make it like this
`->where(function ($query){
   $query->where('tickets.created_at',
    Carbon::now()->subDays()->format('d'))
    ->where('tickets.pre_order',1);       
  })->orWhere(function ($query){
   $query->where('tickets.created_at',
    Carbon::now()->format('d'))
    ->where('tickets.pre_order',0);
  })->get();`

Answer (score 2):

To subtract a day and format it, use [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) library for DateTime in PHP (as given in comments by @spartyboy )

```php
$query
->join('cities','tickets.city_id','=','cities.id')
->select(
  'tickets.id',
  'tickets.biker_id',
  'tickets.picked_up',
  'tickets.delivered',
  'tickets.service_charge',
  'tickets.amount',
  'tickets.cancelled',
  'tickets.pre_order',
  'tickets.created_by',
  'tickets.created_at'
)
->where(function ($query) { 
    $query
    ->where('tickets.pre_order', 0)
    ->whereDay('tickets.created_at', Date('d'));
})
->orWhere(function ($query) { 
    $query
    ->where('tickets.pre_order', 1)
    ->whereDay('tickets.created_at', Carbon::yesterday()->format('d'));
})
->orderBy('tickets.created_at','desc')
->get();
```

or if you want to subtract multiple days then
instead of `yesterday()` use `now()->subDays($days_count)`

Comment: my aim is i will subtract 1 day only if the tickets.pre_order is equal to 1 but if the ticket.pre_order is equal to 0 i will use the whereday('tickets.created_at',Date('d'))

Comment: you can use additional query for that. I'm editing my answer accordingly